# Getting error in ionic 2 framework installing error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

Today I want to start with ionic Framework but soon I realize that I am unable to install Ionic framework properly getting error

1. First I install nods js in my computer. (perfectly)
2. Then I open node js command prompt and add this line **`npm
   install -g cordova ionic`** and get

[image]

3. Then I run this line **`ionic start myApp blank`** and get this error

[image]

4. Then I try to run my app so I get this error

[image]

Comment: looks like `npm install` command failed.. can you try deleting node_modules folder in your app directory and running `npm i` again?

Comment: how to run npm i ? Actually i am new to node

Comment: run in your project folder in cmd..

Comment: i just removed the node_modules folder and try to run my project. It want to re install the ./node_module and when i am reinstalling it gives me [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i    error